# UIPageViewController hard cover as well as page curl animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, page-curl

I'm trying to give animation like hardcover page turn effect for first and last page and simple page curl (default for `UIPageViewController`) to give an album type touch. Can anyone help me to do this using `UIPageViewController`? I need to display like this as in Mosaic photobook app:

For First page ,
http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/10/22/PhotoBookCoverShuffle.png

For all pages except last hard cover
http://techpicky.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Mosaic.png

And Last page should close the Album

No one has helped yet. :(

Comment: The question, in its current form, reads as though you're trying to get one of us to write an app for you.  If that's so, may I recommend [SE::Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), else tell us what you've tried.

Comment: did you get what you want ? Please reply

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many 3rd party libraries. You can try out and modified that according to your needs. Following are some of them.

https://github.com/mpospese/MPFlipViewController

https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pagecurl

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am not able to find the solution here . Actually I want to give this Page Flip and page curl both animations in my App. Please suggest me any alternate way

Comment: This is not what I required, please suggest me some another way

Comment: I couldn't find solution exactly to this question please anybody suggest any new idea or links